# Is it possible to use a bicubic sampler in metal?

Tags: metal

In the compute shader, I can see that bicubic is an option but only if `__HAVE_BICUBIC_FILTERING__` is defined. When I set bicubic as the filtering option, I get a syntax error. **Linear** or **Nearest** compile fine. I'm building for **metal 2** on **MacOS**.

Another method would be to define the sampler on the CPU with a sampler descriptor but there is no option for bicubic there either.

The comments in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43069257/how-to-use-mtlblitcommandencoder-for-copying-interlaced-video-fields-into-a-mtlb) discuss their inability to set **bicubic**.

I've searched the [metal shading language specification](https://developer.apple.com/metal/Metal-Shading-Language-Specification.pdf), and bicubic is not mentioned there at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of device, operating system (version and type), and processor architecture.
The code below can be easy compiled on the following configurations: **iOS 15**, **iPhone 12 / 13**, **Xcode 13**.

```
#if defined(__HAVE_BICUBIC_FILTERING__)
    constexpr sampler textureSampler (mag_filter::bicubic, min_filter::bicubic);
    const half4 colorSample = colorTexture.sample (textureSampler, in.textureCoordinate);
    return float4(colorSample);
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you Hamid. The deployment target of 10.15 won't compile with bicubic, but 11.0 will.

Comment: You're welcome, James.